# Can we equivalently write $x\in y$ as $x\subseteq \cup y$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I was thinking about if these two are equivalent?

I am sure that this is very obvious and I am just not very sure whether or not is this true? Here is a few things I thought of:

$x\in y\Longrightarrow\{x\}\subseteq y\Longrightarrow \cup \{x\}\subseteq\cup y\Longrightarrow x\subseteq \cup y.$ I think these arguments also go the other way if we note $\cup a\subseteq \cup b$ then $a\subseteq b$?

Any suggestion is very much welcomed!

Comment: Hint: is $1\in\{\{1,2\},\{3,4\}\}$?

Comment: Say $x=\varnothing$ and $y=\{\{\varnothing\}\}$. Then $x\notin y$, but certainly $x\subseteq \cup y$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$\emptyset\subseteq \cup y$ for all $y$, but it isn't always the case that $\emptyset\in y$.

Comment: Ah yes! Nicely spotted! I guess a follow up question that I would like to ask is am I right in thinking that my false argument breaks down at '$\cup a\subseteq \cup b$ then $a\subseteq b$' because this is simple not true?

Comment: @JustWandering Essentially yes. Off the top of my head, I would say that for a set $y$ the condition $[\forall x\subseteq \cup y, x\in y]$ is equivalent to $[\exists z, y=\mathcal P(z)]$ and to $[y=\mathcal P(\cup y)]$.